# Query For Completed Levels

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to Mongo/Node.js. I'm creating a small game where users complete levels. When they complete a level, I'm marking it as "complete"

I'm looking to create an API route. Essentially I want to:

- Search the database for User ID
- Find if the user ID has completed level 1, level 2, etc

I've created this so far...

```
api.get('/levelGet', (req,res) => {
  LevelsComplete.findById(req.params.level1, (err, level1) =>{
if (err) {
  res.send(err);
}
res.json(level1);
  });
});
```

I know how to search for one item but wasn't sure how to search for multiple

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a single player game, you may want to store the completed levels in the player document for easier access. This can be done with a comma separated array that is parsed afterwards, or with a similar method.

For reference, here is how you could get a cursor to multiple Mongo documents,

LevelsComplete.find({is_completed: true})

That will find any levels that have been completed. You'll need to add the rest of the node.js stuff to it.